# How to create a unique URL that does not hide the actual URL?

Tags: url

I'm putting a banner ad in a newsletter. I want to be able to track hits from that ad. To do so, I need the ad to direct to a unique URL, but I don't want the URL to be deceptive (ie. a bit.ly URL).

Is there a tag or something else I can attach to my URL to make it unique & trackable?

Answer (score 2):

Use a GUID. Many mailing list managers - eg phplist - will do it for you. The url will look like http://blah.com/sna/fu/AEFB-CDEF-FEEB-1234-5678/wahtever.png

Comment: Instead of a plain guid, I'd recommend base64 encoding the guid.  For example: http://blah.com/sna/fu/6zducasdfasdf/whatever.png